# <li> tags are sometimes not displayed properly (bug?)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, html-lists

I'm dealing with a weird problem. I don't know if it is a bug or something else but sometimes, `li` tags are displayed in a weird way.

[image]

It's about one from twenty page refreshes. Did anybody come around this bug? I really don't know how to avoid this behavior.

After refresh, it works correctly.

[image]

We use overriden `Bootstrap`. This happens on multiple PCs on `Chrome`.

**EDIT:**

Top of the `html` file:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, shrink-to-fit=no">
```

Comment: *"It's about one from twenty page refreshes"* is far from being enough information to debug on. This is not a guessing process. You should  systematically reduce the number of possible causes until you create a [mcve]. As in ***"exactly one from one page refreshes"***. Also keep in mind we can only inspect code, not images. It could be related to character encoding, but this is a wild guess. And without further info it's all I can provide.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `•` is encoded as *CP-1252* instead of UTF-8.

If you check the [encodings table](http://www.i18nqa.com/debug/utf8-debug.html), then you see that this symbol is in *UTF-8* composed of bytes %E2, %80, %A2. Which, in *CP-1252*, is respectively â, € and ¢.

The solution is to use *UTF-8* instead of *CP-1252* to **read**, **write**, **store**, and **display** the characters. The exact answer depends on the server side platform / database / programming language used. If you are sending a wrong encoded header that overwrite the .html meta tag then it will still be displayed as `â€¢` no matter what encoding the browser use.

Since you described your problem to only manifest randomly (?), your best chance would be to check from back to front that all your encoding are *UTF-8*, from your code editors to your database connectors

---

For more info: [Unicode - How to get the characters right?](http://balusc.omnifaces.org/2009/05/unicode-how-to-get-characters-right.html)

Comment: Yes, I use newest version of Chrome and there is <meta charset="utf-8">. The problem is that this issue doesn't appear everytime I go to the page, it's like random.

Comment: @milanoslesarik this certainly is an encoding problem, I've just editted my answer to provide more information. To sum it up, just make sure everything you use to read, write, store and display the page is using the UTF-8 encoding. Goodlucks